# POST JSON and auth SSO sites with python

Tags: python, single-sign-on

I need to post and authenticate SSO sites in Python. I try to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json
import urllib2
import requests
import urlparse
```

Class SSO

```
 ##########################
class SSOSite(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self,baseurl,login_page='/'):
        super(SSOSite,self).__init__()
        self.baseurl=baseurl
        self.login_url=urlparse.urljoin(baseurl,login_page)

    def login(self,username,password):
        # Fix this, assumes all sites take 'email' and 'password' as params.
        payload={'email':username,'password':password}
        return self.post(self.login_url,data=payload)
```

Define action

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    #create any number of SSOSite objects
    s=SSOSite('https://example.com')
    print s.login('myuser', 'mypassword')
    # <Response [200]>
    print s.get('https://example.com/incident.do?JSON&sysparm_action=insert')
    # <Response [200]>
    url = 'https://example.com/incident.do?JSON&sysparm_action=insert'
```

Send JSON content

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
content = {"short_description": "ALERTA DE VULNERABILIDADE", "priority": "1", "description": "O Servidor esta fora"}

#s = requests.get(url, data=json.dumps(content), headers=headers)
s = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(content), headers=headers)
s.raise_for_status()
print s
```

The response is `<Response [200]>` but is not Ok. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The response is what?

Comment: I need to confirm the authentication and post the JSON, but is not work

Comment: How can I mark response as inline code?